# Подключение к ms sql server через приложения

Tags: sql-server

Подключаюсь к бд через microsoft sql managment studio, все нормально, создаю: таблицы, бд, делаю запросы и все такое(рис.1). 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне нужно настроить бд так, чтобы можно было к ней подключаться через порт 1433, через приложения. Вот тут начинаются проблемы. Как я понял, для настройки нужно сначала запустить сервис Sql server agent, но при попытке запуска возникает ошибка(рис.2).
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я не знаю с чем она связана, прогуглил весь интернет, все перепробовал. В службе настройки sql сервера вылезает ошибка(рис.3)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помогите плз настроить эту бд правильным образом.

Comment: А где код, как вы подключаетесь и сообщение об ошибке ?

Comment: Если вы подключаетесь "через приложение" с той же машины, без явного указания порта и протокола, просто задавая имя сервера - *ничего настраивать не нужно*.
SQL Agent вам не нужен - это служба для запуска задач по расписанию, и в SQL Server Express он не работает.

Answer (score 2):

Вам необходимо активировать протокол TCP/IP в настройках SQL Server, в Express редакции доступ к серверу по протоколу TCP/IP **по умолчанию отключен**, подробнее [тут](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/default-sql-server-network-protocol-configuration)

Вам надо его включить:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

1. Вам не нужен SQL Agent - это для настройки расписаний
2. Вам не нужно активировать SQL Browser - он нужен для поиска доступных экземпляров SQL Server в локальной сети, точнее для того, что бы таким способом нашли ваш сервер.